# Slideshow program to use with Raspbian and OpenGL?

Tags: driver, opengles

I have a Pi 3 Model B+ which I wanted to use as a device to show a slideshow for images on a screen. I'm using Raspbian and was happy with FEH, but since another program ("redshift", a blue light filter) required me to use the OpenGL driver half of the images displayed with FEH do not show/work (just a black screen).

Does anyone know slideshow programs that work in OpenGL? It would be great if they supported .gifs also.

Sorry, I am a total noob with Linux. Thanks.

[EDIT] Alright, I ended up with Gwenview, as it works with OpenGL, supports .gifs and even plays video formats like .webm (as well as the Pi can manage). Great program.

Comment: If you find a solution please make an answer. This will finish your question and show other users that it has a solution.

Comment: @TooOldToStart you can also answer your own question below.